# Google Docs Pages Connected

Tags: google-docs

Today in my English class, I was working in a Google Doc and was bored. I double clicked on the space between pages. All of a sudden, the pages sort of "connected."

[image: (Screenshot here)]

I had seen this happen on other students computers (or at least the aftermath of it) and had tried to fix it, as it messes with formatting, but had no luck. Unfortunately, it also happens with any new Google Doc I make. Has anyone had any luck reversing this? And how?

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the "layout" mode:
menu / display / layout (left click on it) and everything returns to normal.

Answer (score 1):

Click view in the top bar, and then click 'show print layout'.

Answer (score 0):

Just double-click the connected line.